# How to pass the func () value of the view element to another Controller

Tags: swift

First I'll start with what I did, and in the end I will describe the problem, so it will be clearer. In general, after Android Studio, working with view elements in Xcode is still a task. I understand that a good programmer will not write the same code twice, so that each time in different Controller does not describe each time the view elements - so I wrote this function in the main Controller

```
class func designForButton (button: UIButton){
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}
```

Then you can access it in different Controller

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonBack: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ViewController.designForButton(button: buttonBack)

}
```

Now, what is not clear. I loaded the framework to work with Toast. And I described its values in the main Controller

```
func designForToast(message: String){
    let style = CSToastStyle.init(defaultStyle: {
    }())
    _ = style?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    _ = style?.titleColor = UIColor.cyan
    _ = style?.messageColor = UIColor.darkGray
    self.view.makeToast(message, duration: 2, position: self.bottomLayoutGuide, title: "title", image: UIImage (named: "logo.jpg"), style: style ) { (success: Bool) in
    }
}
```

But the matter is that in this case I can address to it exclusively in the same Controller

```
_=self.designForToast(message: "Its a Toast")
```

As soon as I want to make `func ()` - like `class func ()` to work in another Controller, Xcode starts to highlight that it's impossible, and due to my small experience, I can not fix it myself.

[image]

Comment: You need to write protocoll and delegate. like in Android Studio, you can't directly call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you add a `viewController` parameter in the method so that it looks like this:

```
static func showToast(message: String, on viewController: UIViewController){ // I also renamed the method as well
    let style = CSToastStyle.init(defaultStyle: {
    }())
    _ = style?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    _ = style?.titleColor = UIColor.cyan
    _ = style?.messageColor = UIColor.darkGray
    viewController.view.makeToast(message, duration: 2, position: viewController.bottomLayoutGuide, title: "title", image: UIImage (named: "logo.jpg"), style: style ) { (success: Bool) in
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you put these "helper functions" in a designated class, like `StyleHelper` or something like that.

Then you can use it like this in a View Controller:

```
StyleHelper.showToast(message: "Hello", on: self)
```

---

Or better yet, make this an extension method!

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showMyToast(message: String){
        let style = CSToastStyle.init(defaultStyle: {
        }())
        _ = style?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        _ = style?.titleColor = UIColor.cyan
        _ = style?.messageColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.view.makeToast(message, duration: 2, position: self.bottomLayoutGuide, title: "title", image: UIImage (named: "logo.jpg"), style: style ) { (success: Bool) in
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this in a View Controller:

```
self.showMyToast(message: "Hello")
```

---

Side Note:

For views that conform to `UIAppearance` protocol, you can access the `appearance()` property to change its style globally. For example, you can do this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = .red
```

And every `UIButton` you create will be red.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define a protocol , and an extension to UIViewController to provide a default implementation for your method.....if this was the question...:P

```
protocol ToastProtocol: class {
    func showToast(message:String)
}

extension ToastProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func showToast(message:String){
        ///yourcode
    }
}
```

After that you can youse your showToast  method in any UIViewController

Comment: Thanks , i`l try it too